# Show element after ng-click angularjs

Tags: angularjs, element, show

I'm looking for angular-way solution for task:

Imagine, we have many rows like

```
<tr>
<td>
 <span>click me</span>
 <span style='display: none;'>i'll be shown</span>
</td>
</tr>
...[a lot as the same rows]...
```

All i want is to show second span and hide first, after click to first span.

p.s. really don't want to use jQuery for this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the view:

```
<span ng-click="onItemClicked(currentItem)">click me</span>
<span ng-show="currentItem.isVisible">I'll be shown</span>
```

And in the controller:

```
  $scope.onItemClicked = function (item) {
    item.isVisible = true;
  };
```

Read the [documentation about ngShow](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow).

Working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/FEZ5JDfVfeWKSGOHjBSy?p=preview

Comment: but he needs to hide the first span

Comment: to hide the first element you can add [ng-hide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide)      `<span ng-hide="currentItem.isVisible" ng-click="onItemClicked(currentItem)">click me</span>`